# Is there any way to recognize the numbers in such image?

Tags: image, ocr, captcha

Below is the image I have, I want to write a program to automatically recognize the numbers in the image.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any additional information that might help? Are the sizes fixed? Are the fonts fixed? are there always a specific number of digits?